# How to assign Azure Managed Identity to Azure Storage Account?

Tags: azure, azure-managed-identity

I am following this tutorial where it required to use an Azure Managed Identity assigned to an Azure Storage Account.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/customer-managed-keys-overview#about-customer-managed-keys

In the tutorial the step 1. is:

> 1. An Azure Key Vault admin grants permissions to encryption keys to the managed identity that's associated with the storage account.

However I cannot find a way to see or assign a managed identity to an SA. It seems that SAs have no managed identities out of the box..

Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so that it's possible to view that in the portal but I am sure that powershell can help you. As far as i know that are two ways to check if your storage account has a Principal Id assigned. One way is to check in azure AD by typing `Get-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName storageAccountName`  and another one is:

```
$stgName = "stgName"
$rgName =  "rgName"

$stg = Get-AzStorageAccount -StorageAccountName $stgName -ResourceGroupName $rgName
$stg.identity
```

if you have managed identity assigned so you can see principal id. Otherwrise:

```
Set-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $rgName -AccountName $stgName -AssignIdentity
```

Comment: Many thanks. I think you are right. As a note, once i created the managed identity there is yet NO way to see it in the Portal. As well as there is NO way in the Portal for Azure Key Vault   to grant permission to the managed identity that's associated with the storage account.

Answer (score 1):

If you did have a managed identity setup it is possible to view in Portal, click on the Json view and you should be able to see the ARM template and if MI is there it will show in the identity section like below.

You can always check via CLI also, if it returns a blank/null then no MI assigned.

```
az storage account show --name <your-storage-account-name> --resource-group <your-resource-group-name> --query "identity"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Managed identity can be assigned using Azure CLI with the command:

```
az storage account update --identity SystemAssigned -n <storage account name>
```